# Click events not responding inside angular components

Tags: angular, templates, events, click, dropdown

I have a template I downloaded from the internet. The template contains bootstrap.js, font-awesome.min.js and some other files. I want to convert the template to Angular project; so I placed all the css and js files inside the ANGUALR.JSON FILE and placed the  contet of the template inside index.html in angular. when I compile using "ng serve" command, the output was ok and all the click events where ok too.

But I don't want the content to be in the index.html in angular, so I created a component for it and placed the content in it. To my surprise the click events as well as the drop-down where not working. I've search the internet I can't find solution yet.

What I've done so far, I've placed "console.log('inside');" into all the js files, when I serve the page. I can see the logs meaning the pages are correctly loaded. But I don't know what else to do

Here is a sample of angular.json

```
       "scripts": [
          "src/assets/products/js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",

          "src/assets/products/js/popper.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/wow.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/animated.headline.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.sticky.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/contact.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.form.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.validate.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/mail-script.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/plugins.js",
          
          "src/assets/products/js/slick.min.js",
          "src/assets/products/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js",

          "src/assets/products/js/main.js",
```

Comment: With the information you have provided it is really hard to know what the problem  is/might be, we can only guess, eg you have not imported Jquery, or you have missed some files while moving the code from index.html

Comment: Show html and Typescript

Comment: the problem in Angular when use jQuery is that JQuery functions generally is called in `$( document ).ready()`. In Angular (or another SPA) the eventdocument.ready is executed before the component is created, so, in any way you need call again the functions in the event `AfterViewInit` of the component. What functions? check the ready() function and execute again (you cna create an script with all the functions).NOTE: in general is not a good idea mixing Angular and jQuery